# Order readonly List

Tags: c#

I have a readonly List so I can hide the Add method from other classes, like this:

```
class Foo
{
    private readonly List<Bar> _Bars = new List<Bar>;
    public()
    {
        this.Bars = _Bars.AsReadOnly();
    }
    public ReadOnlyCollection<Bar> Bars
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public void AddBar(Vector Dimensions)
    {
        _Bars.Add(new Bar(Dimensions));
    }
}
```

The thing is, now I want to order the _Bars field of an instance of Foo, like such:

```
public void OrderBarsByVolume()
{
    _Bars.OrderByDescending(o => o.Volume); //Doesn't do anything
    _Bars = _Bars.OrderByDescending(o => o.Volume).ToList();  //Error: A readonly field cannot be assigned to
}
```

Is it possible to use orderby and keep the add feature of the List hidden from other classes?

Comment: Don't make it `readonly`!

Comment: @tolanj That can't be done...VS says it is not possible to convert type `ReadOnlyCollection` to `List` via a reference conversion, etc...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not with your current implementation, however, if you adjust things slightly then yes you can. The idea of "*hiding*" the underlying data means you don't have to hold it internally as read only but rather *expose* it as read only

```
private List<Bar> _Bars = new List<Bar>();

public ReadOnlyCollection<Bar> Bars
{
    get { return _Bars.AsReadOnly(); }
}

public void OrderBy(Func<Bar, bool> src)
{
    _Bars = _Bars.OrderByDescending(src);
}
...

var foo = new Foo();
foo.OrderBy(x => x.Volume);
```

If you feel creating a new `ReadOnlyCollection` each time is too expensive then keep your code as it is but simply remove the `readonly` modifier

```
private List<Bar> _Bars = new List<Bar>;

public void OrderBy(Func<Bar, bool> src)
{
    _Bars = _Bars.OrderByDescending(src).ToList();
}
```

Comment: `get { return _Bars.AsReadOnly(); }` would create a new list everytime I called the `Bars` property, wouldn't it? That would make it costly, that's why I opted for making it `readonly` and setting it `AsReadOnly` only once, as I saw on another question...

Comment: @TeaWithCookies Define "costly"? Have you benchmarked it? How often are you accessing the property? You can always look at caching *externally* if this becomes an issue, however, as far as I am aware `AsReadOnly` is the equivalent to `new ReadOnlyCollection<Bar>(_Bars)` and unless you have a *massive* list, any degrade in performance would be more or less negligible.

Comment: Well, I don't know if it would degrade performance, the list has about 5000 objects...so everytime it is accessed it is copied entirely...

Comment: @TeaWithCookies if you have *measured* performance and you feel it's an issue then there is another way around the problem (see update). However, my advice is don't *assume* something is going to be slow, benchmark it with real data and make a decision based on that - you might be surprised.

Comment: `new ReadOnlyCollection()` doesn't copy the items. It holds the entire list as reference. So while changing is not possible, it will reflect changes to the underlying list.

Comment: @Oliver I'm aware, but that wasn't part of the requirement if you re-read the question.

Comment: You're right. It's just about the comments that say, it could be costly depending on the list size. But that's wrong, cause the original list will be wrapped. So it doesn't matter if the underlying list is 100 or 1.000.000 elements. A read-only list won't copy the items.

Comment: @Oliver yeah good point in that respect, I wasn't ever convinced there would be performance issue anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Use `List<T>.Sort` method

```
_Bars.Sort((x,y) => x.Volume.CompareTo(y.Volume));
```

Comment: the purpose of the assigment is ordering.

Comment: It works, but only by ascending order of volume. How do I make it sort by descending volume?

Comment: @TeaWithCookies reverse the comparison `y.Volume.CompareTo(x.Volume)`

Comment: Thanks! Any idea why `_Bars.OrderByDescending(o => o.Volume);` doesn't do anything?

Comment: @TeaWithCookies `Sort()` will reorder the actual collection. The linq functions will not; they return a _new_ `IEnumerable` which contains the reordered elements. So you need to assign that.

Answer (score 1):

Add a public method that will do the ordering within the Foo object.

Answer (score 1):

Even if James gave you some good tips, there are still some open issues.

So let's start with your implementation:

```
private readonly List<Bar> _Bars = new List<Bar>;
```

This won't make the list itself read-only. Still it is possible to add, remove an item or to clear the entire list. The keyword `readonly` only ensure that you can't replace the whole list by a completely different list.

So what you like, is that within your class you have full access to the list (so `Foo` can add, remove, sort items), but anybody who requested the list, can only read this list. The open question here would be what should happen if someone requested the list and afterwards the list was changed from Foo. Should the already outgiven list reflect theses changes or not? Mostly you like this behaviour, but it really depends on what you like to achieve.

Here is my code example that should solve most of your problems:

```
internal class Foo
{
    // The list which can be manipulated only be Foo itself.
    private List<Bar> _Bars;

    // The proxy that will be given out to the consumers.
    private ReadOnlyCollection<Bar> _BarsReadOnly;

    public Foo()
    {
       // Create the mutable list.
        _Bars = new List<Bar>();
       // This is a wrapper class that holds a
       // reference to the mutable class, but
       // throws an exception to all change methods. 
        _BarsReadOnly = _Bars.AsReadOnly();
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<Bar> Bars
    {
        // Simply give out the wrapper.
        get { return _BarsReadOnly; }
    }

    public void AddBar(Vector dimensions)
    {
        // Manipulate the only intern available
        // changeable list...
        _Bars.Add(new Bar(dimensions));
    }

    public void SortBars()
    {
       // To change the order of the list itself
       // call the Sort() method of list with
       // a comparer that is able to sort the list
       // as you like.
        _Bars.Sort(BarComparer.Default);

       // The method OrderBy() won't have any
       // immediate effect.
       var orderedList = _Bars.OrderBy(i => i.Volume);
       // That's because it will just create an enumerable
       // which will iterate over your given list in
       // the desired order, but it won't change the
       // list itself and so also not the outgiven wrappers!
    }
}
```

To use the `Sort()` method of the list class you need an comparer but that's quite easy to implement:

```
internal class BarComparer : IComparer<Bar>
{
    public static BarComparer Default = new BarComparer();

    public int Compare(Bar x, Bar y)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y))
            return 0;

        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null))
            return -1;

        if (ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return 1;

        return x.Volume.CompareTo(y.Volume);
    }
}
```

I hope this gives you a little more enlightenment about how stuff in C# works.

Answer (score 0):

Let the callers handle the sorted list:

```
public IEnumerable<Bars> OrderedBars(Func<Bar, bool> sortMethod)
{
    return _Bars.OrderBy(sortMethod);
}
```

If you really want to keep the sorted bars to yourself, you could create a immutable class where ordering the bars create a new instance of `Foo` which will then either replace the current one or be used by the caller, something like that:

```
public Foo OrderBarsByVolume()
{
    return new Foo() {_Bars = this._Bars.OrderByDescending(o => o.Volume)}
}
```